# How can I delete OU with PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to create a gui where among other requirements need to delete Global Groups and Organizational Units. I have the function to delete the groups working but I need to be able to delete OU as well.

Im using this code for the groups:

```
 private void btn_verwijderGG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        GroupPrincipal ou = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, txt_OUNaam.Text);

        if (ou != null)
        {
            ou.Delete();
            MessageBox.Show("OU" + txt_OUNaam.Text + "is verwijderd");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OU niet gevonden");
        }
    }
```

But how can I change te GroupPrincipal to ou? Or what do I need to do to do this?

Comment: You have to use DirectoryEntry for this. Use MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentries.remove?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have used in the past to delete an OU (**but use with great caution**)

1. Use the root as SearchBase ... to look under a certain parent OU
2. Use DirectorySearcher to search for all OUs that match the filter
3. Loop through the results and Delete them.
4. Ensure you have permissions to delete the OU and that the OU does not have "Prevent Accidental Protection" turned on.

```
    public void DeleteOU (string ldap, string filterOU)
    {
        // ldap = "LDAP://DC=fabri,DC=com"
        // filteredOU = "OU=OUName" or "CN=OUName" depending on how its configured.

        DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(ldap);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);
        searcher.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)({filterOU}))";

        try
        {
            foreach (SearchResult res in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                DirectoryEntry thisOU = res.GetDirectoryEntry();
                thisOU.DeleteTree();
                thisOU.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something with exception. Most likely, Not Found.
        }
    }
```